# How to set default character encoding for a a runnable jar?

Tags: java, character-encoding, executable-jar

I have a very large Java program that needs to default to UTF-8 encoding. When I run it in eclipse, I can just change the default character encoding to UTF-8 in Run Configurations, but the encoding is something else whenever I export the code as a runnable jar rendering the text unreadable. Is there a way to set the default encoding when compiling a jar? My program reads from 20+ files, so it would be inefficient to specify character encoding every time I read or write (although possible if there is no other way). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible to do at compile time. You'll need to set the `file.encoding` system property when launching the JVM, or change your code to specify an charset. As painful as it may be, I would recommend the second option; relying on the default charset is seldom a good idea.

See also:
[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)